# How to UPDATE JOIN data from another database table with different connection?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I have codes below that can update and inner join data with another table within a database, also it uses only one connection string because they are both in the same database.

```vb
Dim connstring1 As String
connstring1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=AMP.accdb"

Dim conn1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connstring1)
Dim updatescardrate As String = "UPDATE scard INNER JOIN Employee_Records ON scard.controlnumber = Employee_Records.controlnumber SET scard.rate = Employee_Records.rate"
Dim cmdupdatescardrate As New OleDbCommand(updatescardrate, conn1)

conn1.Open()
cmdupdatescardrate.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn1.Close()
```

Sample expected result illustration:

```sql
UPDATE Table scard.column1 '(this is from connection1, database: AMP.accdb)'
and JOIN data from Table criteria.column3 '(this is from connection2, database: IMS.accdb)'
```

Connection1:

```
Dim connstring1 As String
connstring1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=AMP.accdb"
```

Connection2:

```
Dim connstring2 As String
connstring2 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=IMS.accdb"
```

Sample expected result illustration:

```sql
UPDATE Table scard.column1 '(this is from connection1, database: AMP.accdb)'
and JOIN data from Table criteria.column3 '(this is from connection2, database: IMS.accdb)'
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Text can be [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a linked table in the first database to the second database. Than you can use both tables as they would be in the 1st one.